# Concatenating dataframes created on different worker machines into a single dataframe

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to write this very small program that is intended to run on a Dask Distributed cluster. On each worker machine there is a CSV file (just one, as of now), the function files is supposed to run on every worker and return a dataframe built from said file. However, I want to analyze them as a single dataframe. I'm trying to build a single dataframe from those two returned by the workers. How could I achieve that?

```py
def files():
    for file in glob.glob("data*.csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        print(df.head())
        column = df["cars"]
        max = column.max()
        print(max)
        return df


client = Client('SCHEDULER:8786')
a = client.submit(files, workers='WORKER1:8786',  pure=False)
b = client.submit(files, workers='WORKER2:8786', pure=False)
c = dd.merge(a, b, left_on=['id', 'cars'], right_on = ['id', 'cars'],  suffixes=['_1', '_2'], how="left")
#c = dd.concat([a,b])
```

After executing the code above two times commenting one of the C's each time keeps the process open and nothing gets returned or shown to the client.

My sample files are detailed below:

```
   id  cars
0   1   223
1   2   333
2   3  1933
3   4  2003
4   5   893
5   6  1233
6   7  1933
   id  cars
0  14   224
1  24   334
2  34  1934
3  44  3004
4  54   894
5  64  1234
6  74  1934

   id  cars
0   1   223
1   2   333
2   3  1933
3   4  2003
4   5   893
5   6  1233
6   7  1933
```

Thus my concatenated dataframe should have a len = len(df_a) + len(df_b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are asking two workers to do the same task of iterating over files and returning the first file's dataframe. Let's make a reproducible fix for this.

This snippet is just to generate some dummy data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# let's create two dummy files
for i in range(2):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns=list("abcde"))
    df.to_csv(f'data{i}.csv', index=False)
```

Now, for the main task you want to submit a task for each worker to load a separate file. Then, for concatenation you can rely on `dd.from_delayed` which will concatenate the dataframes from the list of futures:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
from glob import glob

# start a client
client = Client()

def get_df(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    return df

list_files = glob('data*.csv')
# map each item in the list to get_df
futures = client.map(get_df, list_files)

# transform futures into dask dataframe (it concatenates them automatically)
ddf = dd.from_delayed(futures)
```

Update: sorry, I misunderstood your situation. So, you are interested in merging dataframes from different workers, so one way to do it is to modify your original code as follows:

```py
a = client.submit(files, workers='WORKER1:8786',  pure=False)
b = client.submit(files, workers='WORKER2:8786', pure=False)
df_a = dd.from_delayed([a])
df_b = dd.from_delayed([b])
df_c = dd.merge(df_a, df_b, left_on=['id', 'cars'], right_on = ['id', 'cars'],  suffixes=['_1', '_2'], how="left")
```

Note that before merging you want to convert your futures into dask dataframes.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for responding. I have a distributed system (multiple machines) so I have modified your code slightly. Removed the param on get_df and added a for loop  to call pd per each file. However, an issue is raised with the line ```futures = client.map(get_df)``` with message ````Dask no longer supports mapping over Iterators or Queues.Consider using a normal for loop and Client.submit```` I tried using the normal loop inside the get_df but failed.

Comment: Thank you again, your update definitively executes. However, when I print the length of the df, the output is the length of just one of the previous two, not both added together. Am I missing something on how merge works? The df_c should have all the elements in df_a and df_b. I have updated my question with schema of my csv files.

Comment: Yes, I did and df_c seems to only be composed of one of the dataframes. I have updated my answer with what is executed when executing df_a,b,c.compute(). In theory, df_c should be all the entries on bf_a and bf_b.  df_c should have 13 indexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229660/discussion-between-nazar-and-sultanorazbayev).

Comment: Please change `how='left'` to `how='outer'` if you want outer merge.

Comment: Thank you so much, this clarified my understanding and fixed my issue. Preceding to accept your answer as it solved my issue.